# NSPredicate and ignore strings with specified format Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array with below values:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x1c804f120>(
Model.sqlite,
Model.sqlite-shm,
Model.sqlite-wal,
iiii,
report,
test,
ttrrr,
tyyyy,
ww,
wwww
)
```

I want to NSPredicate array and ignore any array content with string format .sqlite and print remaining like below:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x1c804f120>(
iiii,
report,
test,
ttrrr,
tyyyy,
ww,
wwww
)
```

I want to know NSPredicate which does this trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF contains[c] %@)",@".sqlite"];
```

Comment: No need for the `NSString stringWithFormat:`. Just do: `NSPredicate* predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF contains[c] %@)", @"Model.sqlite"];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NOT CONTAINS**, and query `.sqlite` string  to filter out

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF CONTAINS %@)", @".sqlite"];
```